# Splitting data frames

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

Am I able to split data frames based the values they start with?

I have a data frame and a column of times. I want to group them in blocks. So I want a data frame for times between 12-3, and another for 3-6, etc. etc. Is there a way I could do this?

I tried using `.groupby()` and got a key error when I entered my values.
Here's my input:

```
    ACC_DATE    ACC_TIME    DAY_OF_WEEK COUNTY_NAME INJURY  COLLISION_WITH_1
978 2012-01-21  0:01    SATURDAY    Harford NO  FIXED OBJ
952 2012-01-21  0:01    SATURDAY    Anne Arundel    NO  VEH
995 2012-01-21  0:01    SATURDAY    Prince Georges  NO  VEH
1059 2012-01-22 0:01    SUNDAY      Carroll        YES  FIXED OBJ
941 2012-01-21  0:01    SATURDAY    Prince Georges  NO  FIXED OBJ
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
17535   2012-12-10  9:12    MONDAY  Frederick   NO  FIXED OBJ
17536   2012-12-10  9:12    MONDAY  Frederick   NO  FIXED OBJ
17251   2012-12-07  9:12    FRIDAY  Anne Arundel NO VEH
17507   2012-12-10  9:12    MONDAY  Dorchester  NO  FIXED OBJ
18636   2012-12-31  9:12    MONDAY  Frederick   YES NON-COLLISION
```

Here's the refined data I'm working with

```
    ACC_TIME    COUNTY_NAME
ACC_TIME        
0:08    0:08    Allegany
0:09    0:09    Allegany
0:09    0:09    Allegany
0:10    0:10    Allegany
0:10    0:10    Allegany
... ... ...
9:09    9:09    Allegany
9:10    9:10    Allegany
9:10    9:10    Allegany
9:11    9:11    Allegany
9:12    9:12    Allegany
```

Here's the code I have

```
#--> First, how can I organize my data for only county & times?
sp = df.drop(['ACC_DATE','DAY_OF_WEEK','INJURY','COLLISION_WITH_1'],axis=1)

#Next, how can I organize the data by county and time of accidents? 
sp_sorted = sp.sort_values(['COUNTY_NAME', 'ACC_TIME'], inplace=True)
# sp_sorted

#Now, I want to split sp by county.
sp.set_index(keys=['COUNTY_NAME','ACC_TIME'], drop=False,inplace=True)
names = sp['COUNTY_NAME'].unique().tolist()
times = sp['ACC_TIME'].unique().tolist()
allegany = sp.loc['Allegany']

allegany
# allegany.groupby(['9','10','11','12'])
```

My expected output is a list of the smaller data frames. I would then use the entries of this list as my x-values in a potential scatter or bar plot. The plot is measuring number of accidents against time blocks (12-3, 3-6, etc.)

Comment: What's the expected output? a list of smaller dataframes? A dictionary of smaller dataframes? It would be great if you could include the input as well as the expected output in your question.

Comment: A list of smaller data frames; I've updated my question. The given code is my input, or do you mean I should provide the entirety of my code?

Comment: The code is fine, but there's no input data (the dataframe you provide doesn't include the column ACC_DATE, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for. In this example, I'm building a list of dataframes out of a single dataframe - based on the column 'a'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], "b": range(6), "c": range(6, 12)})

==>
   a  b   c
0  1  0   6
1  1  1   7
2  1  2   8
3  2  3   9
4  2  4  10
5  2  5  11
```

Now build the list of dataframes:

```
df_list = []
def to_list(df):
    df_list.append(df.copy())
    return pd.Series(range(3))
df.groupby("a", as_index = False).apply(to_list)
```

The output:

```
print(df_list[0])
#    a  b  c
# 0  1  0  6
# 1  1  1  7
# 2  1  2  8

print(df_list[1])
#    a  b   c
# 3  2  3   9
# 4  2  4  10
# 5  2  5  11
```

If the column you'd like to group by is of type datetime, you can also do that:

```
dates = pd.date_range("2020-01-01 00:00", periods=15, freq = "19min")

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": dates, "b": range(len(dates)), "c": range(10, 10+len(dates))})
print(df.head())
==>

                    a  b   c
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00  0  10
1 2020-01-01 00:19:00  1  11
2 2020-01-01 00:38:00  2  12
3 2020-01-01 00:57:00  3  13
4 2020-01-01 01:16:00  4  14
        
df_list = []
df.groupby(df.a.dt.hour, as_index = False).apply(to_list)
print(df_list[1])
==>

                    a  b   c
4 2020-01-01 01:16:00  4  14
5 2020-01-01 01:35:00  5  15
6 2020-01-01 01:54:00  6  16

print(df_list[2])
==>
                    a  b   c
7 2020-01-01 02:13:00  7  17
8 2020-01-01 02:32:00  8  18
9 2020-01-01 02:51:00  9  19
```

Comment: What if the entries of column a were: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, and so on. Would there be a way so that the data frame you build consists of all entries that start with '1'? That's essentially what I want to do in that I want a data frame to consist of all entries that start with '9', for instance. So 9:00, 9:01, 9:02, etc. etc.

Comment: Are these different times of day?

Comment: (see my latest edit) Does this answer your question?

Comment: Wow, yes absolutely it does. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great. Do you mind accepting my answer for future generations? (clicking the checkbox next to my answer, turning it from grey to green)